# C addition using modulus

Tags: c, addition, modulo

I came across an intriguing C code that prints `A + B`, but I have trouble understanding it.

### Input Format:

```
A B
```

where `A`, `B` are integers between `0` and `10` separated by a single space.

### Code:

```
main( n )
{
    gets( &n );
    printf("%d", n % 85 - 43);
}
```

This was intended for short coding, please don't mind the warnings.

### What I understand so far:

`gets( &n )` stores the ASCII values of A, space, and B in the lower three bytes of `n`. For example, `A = 3` and `B = 8` would yield `n = 0x00382033`. Given conditions prevent `n` from overflowing. But I do not understand how `n % 85 - 43` yields `A + B`.

How do you come up with these numbers?

Comment: Intriguing indeed.

Comment: A hint is that 85 is alternating bits in binary, `01010101`. If you try this approach with `10101010`, that is the number 170, you get similar functionality, the only difference being if you do with `0 0` you get the number 128 instead (which is `10000000` in binary). A similar technique is used to do a bunch of optimizations with bitwise operations such as counting number of bits in a bit set using masks such as `0x55555555` and `0xAAAAAAAA` (0x55 = 85 and 0xAA = 170). If you google those hexadecimal codes you get a bunch of interesting articles.

Comment: Wow, i never expected this much depth in the number 85. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I assume you mean between 0 and 9 inclusive?

Comment: That's definitely [ioccc](https://www.ioccc.org/) worthy.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

With little-endian ints (and assuming ASCII text, and 8-bit bytes, and all the other assumptions the code requires), and ignoring all the technically-wrong-in-modern-C stuff in the code, your "What I understand so far" is correct.

`gets(&n)` will store the ASCII values of A, space, and B into the first 3 bytes of `n`. It'll also store a null terminator into the 4th byte. Storing those ASCII values into those bytes of `n` results in `n` taking the value `B*256*256 + space*256 + A`, where `B`, `space`, and `A` represent the corresponding ASCII values.

256 mod 85 is 1, so by the properties of modular arithmetic,

```
(B*256*256 + space*256 + A) % 85 = (B + space + A) % 85
```

Incidentally, with 4-byte big-endian ints, we get

```
(A*256*256*256 + space*256*256 + B*256) % 85 = (B + space + A) % 85
```

so endianness doesn't matter, as long as we have 4-byte ints. (Bigger or smaller ints could be a problem; for example, with 8-byte ints, we'd have to worry about what's in the bytes of `n` that `gets` didn't set.)

Space is ASCII 32, and the ASCII value for a digit character is 48 + the value of the digit. Defining `a` and `b` as the numeric values of the digits entered (rather than the ASCII values of the digit characters), we have

```
(B + space + A) % 85 = (b + 48 + 32 + a + 48) % 85
                     = (a + b + 128) % 85
                     = (a + b + 43) % 85

(B + space + A) % 85 - 43 = (a + b + 43) % 85 - 43
                          = (a + b) % 85
                          = a + b
```

where the last two equivalences rely on the fact that `a` and `b` take values from 0 to 9.